# Read string buffer using sscanf

Tags: c, sockets, segmentation-fault, scanf

I have a TCP server transmitting JSON formatted strings over a standard TCP socket.
The message consists of :| length of JSON object | JSON object |

On the client I need to take this message and parse it.
So first I extract the length using sscanf, move the pointer sscanf'ed bytes, and extract the JSON message.
Currently I'm stuck at the sscanf part, and get an "address out of bounds" error while trying to extract integer value from the string buffer.

Why does this happen? please help.

```
static void * oom_collect_xcvr_data_thread(void *arg)
{
    int offset = 0;
    int recv_len, data_size;
    char *recv_buf = NULL;
    json_t *json_obj = NULL;
    json_error_t j_error;

    recv_buf = calloc(OOM_BUF_SIZE, 1);
    CASSERT(recv_buf != NULL);

    while(1)
    {
        if((recv_len = recv(sock_fd, recv_buf, OOM_BUF_SIZE, 0)) <= 0)
        {
            printf("server connect: tcp receive error %s", strerror(errno));
            free(recv_buf);
            CASSERT(0);
        }

        while(offset < recv_len)
        {
            offset += sscanf(recv_buf + offset, "%d \n", &data_size);
            if ((json_obj = json_loadb(recv_buf + offset, data_size, 0, &j_error)) == NULL)
            {
                    printf("line: %d, column: %d, position: %d, source: %s, Error: %s"
                            ,j_error.line, j_error.column, j_error.position, j_error.source, j_error.text); 
            }

            offset += data_size;
            copy_xcvr_info(json_obj);
        }
        CASSERT(offset == recv_len);
        offset = 0;
    }
}
```

String data I'm trying to parse:

```
1905
{  
   "static":{  
      "RX_POWER_HIGH_ALARM":2.5,
      "LENGTH_SMF":10000,
      "update_timestamp":251739.961,
      "ENCODING":6,
      "ENHANCED_OPTIONS":240,
      "LENGTH_SMF_KM":10000,
      "TX_POWER_LOW_ALARM":-8.0,
      "CONNECTOR":7,
      "DIAGNOSTIC_MONITORING_TYPE":104,
      "TRANSCEIVER_EXT":0,
      "VENDOR_PN":"FTLX1471D3BCL",
      "RX_POWER_LOW_WARN":-18.01,
      "WAVELENGTH":1310,
      "OPTIONS":"001a",
      "LENGTH_OM4_OR_CU":0,
      "TEMP_HIGH_WARN":73.0,
      "TEMP_LOW_ALARM":-13.0,
      "BR_NOMINAL":10300,
      "VOLTAGE_LOW_ALARM":2.9,
      "BIAS_HIGH_ALARM":85.0,
      "LENGTH_62_5UM":0,
      "VOLTAGE_LOW_WARN":3.0,
      "RATE_IDENTIFIER":0,
      "BIAS_LOW_ALARM":15.0,
      "VENDOR_OUI":"009065",
      "BIAS_LOW_WARN":20.0,
      "CABLE_SPEC":"0000",
      "TX_POWER_HIGH_WARN":1.0,
      "EXT_IDENTIFIER":4,
      "update_count":1,
      "VENDOR_SN":"UK70M7N",
      "VOLTAGE_HIGH_ALARM":3.7,
      "TX_POWER_HIGH_ALARM":2.0,
      "IDENTIFIER":3,
      "LENGTH_OM3":0,
      "BR_MIN":10300,
      "TEMP_HIGH_ALARM":78.0,
      "SFF_8472_COMPLIANCE":3,
      "RX_POWER_LOW_ALARM":-20.0,
      "VOLTAGE_HIGH_WARN":3.6,
      "BIAS_HIGH_WARN":80.0,
      "TRANSCEIVER":"2000000000000000",
      "LENGTH_50UM":0,
      "TX_POWER_LOW_WARN":-7.0,
      "VENDOR_REV":"A",
      "DATE_CODE":"110212",
      "RX_POWER_HIGH_WARN":2.0,
      "VENDOR_NAME":"FINISAR CORP.",
      "BR_MAX":10300,
      "TEMP_LOW_WARN":-8.0
   },
   "port_name":"port18",
   "port_type":"SFP",
   "dynamic":{  
      "L_TX_POWER_WARN":0,
      "update_timestamp":253134.25,
      "L_TX_POWER_ALARM":0,
      "TX_POWER":0.68,
      "L_RX_POWER_ALARM":0,
      "DATA_READY_BAR_STATE":0,
      "RS_1_STATE":0,
      "TX_DISABLE_STATE":0,
      "L_TEMP_WARN":0,
      "L_VCC_ALARM":0,
      "L_ALARM_WARN":"000000000000",
      "SOFT_RATE_SELECT":0,
      "TX_FAULT_STATE":0,
      "L_TEMP_ALARM":0,
      "TX_POWER_DBM":-1.68,
      "VCC":3.41,
      "TEMPERATURE":32.99,
      "TX_BIAS":37.19,
      "STATUS_CONTROL":0,
      "L_BIAS_ALARM":0,
      "RX_LOS_STATE":0,
      "OPT_LASER_TEMP":0.0,
      "L_BIAS_WARN":0,
      "RX_POWER_DBM":-1.28,
      "SOFT_TX_DISABLE_SELECT":0,
      "L_RX_POWER_WARN":0,
      "OPT_TEC":0.0,
      "RX_POWER":0.75,
      "L_VCC_WARN":0,
      "RATE_SELECT_STATE":0
   }
}
```

gdb error message:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
rawmemchr () at ../sysdeps/i386/rawmemchr.S:70
70      ../sysdeps/i386/rawmemchr.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  rawmemchr () at ../sysdeps/i386/rawmemchr.S:70
#1  0xf63de127 in _IO_str_init_static_internal (sf=0xee807838, ptr=0x969d046 <Address 0x969d046 out of bounds>, size=157929542, pstart=0x0) at strops.c:45
#2  0xf63d1c43 in _IO_vsscanf (string=0x969d046 <Address 0x969d046 out of bounds>, format=0x80d5fb7 "%d \n", args=0xee807908 "\260\202\200\356") at iovsscanf.c:44
#3  0xf63bf59b in __sscanf (s=0x969d046 <Address 0x969d046 out of bounds>, format=0x80d5fb7 "%d \n") at sscanf.c:34
#4  0x08091013 in oom_collect_xcvr_data_thread (arg=0x0) at /home/sfreeman/wspace/swapp/src/interface/agent/ia_l2.c:172
#5  0xf730f954 in start_thread (arg=0xee808b70) at pthread_create.c:304
#6  0xf644295e in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/clone.S:130
```

Comment: What field is the JSON message?

Comment: JSON object is all the data encapsulated within '{'  '}', right after 1905 comes the JSON message

Comment: You are assuming that recv() returns all the data in one read. It can(and will)  in fact read small portions of the data. Also: read() returning -1 is **not an error** check errno before bailing out.

Comment: I would suggest to always to use a [json aware tool](https://www.google.pl/search?q=cjson).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sscanf` causes `SIGSEGV` when the receive buffer is full and doesn't end with 0. You need to ensure the received data is terminated with 0, e.g.:

```
recv_len = recv(sock_fd, recv_buf, OOM_BUF_SIZE - 1, 0);
if(recv_len > 0) {
    recv_buf[recv_len] = 0;
}
else {
    // Handle disconnect or error.
}
```

---

I also spotted the following errors:

- The code cannot handle partial messages.
- `sscanf` returns the number of items assigned, not the number of consumed bytes, like the code expects.
- No checking of `sscanf` return value for errors.
- No checking whether the number has been received in full. `sscanf` format `" \n"` matches 0-length string, contrary to what the code expects.

Reading `sscanf` man page in its entirety is required to be able to use it correctly.